# Cant understand the behavior of setcookie() function in php

Tags: php

why the following code is displaying "mamun" in the browser instead of "sajib"? Please explain the mechanism..

```
<?php 

$exp = time() + 3600;

setcookie("name", "sajib", $exp);
echo $_COOKIE["name"];

setcookie("name", "mamun", $exp);

?>
```

Comment: How do you test script?

Comment: You can access the cookie only after a reload of the page. Means after your first reload the cookie: `name` has the value `mamun`. Then you set it to `sajib`, which you will be able to access after a next reload, but now the value is still `mamun` and that's why you get that output. And if you would reload it again, same happens ^^. Means you will never be able to output `sajib` here.

Answer (score 0):

When you use setcookie() a cookie will be set on client's browser. In next page loads, cookie will send back to your website's webserver.

So, you can't immediately access to new cookies in same process that you set the cookie.

But you can use `$_COOKIE['name'] = 'sajib'` just after/before `setcookie()`, so $_COOKIE array will change to new value.

Comment: Also, you can't send header data (also cookies) to browsers after sending content (e.g. by echo). You MUST send headers, then contents.